# Add role in meteor user

Tags: meteor, roles

I'm new in **Meteor**, and trying to build an **todo** app using **Meteor**. For user sign up and sign in, I'm using `accounts-ui, accounts-password, accounts-facebook, accounts-google`. In my view page, I just write `{{> loginButtons}}`, and all user sign in and sign up done automatically. Now my problem is how can I add here `roles`. I have already added `alanning:roles`, but can't understand how can I add roles here. Because I don't write any code. Any suggestion ???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Because I don't write any code"? The `alanning:roles` package may be exactly what you need.

Comment: yeah, you're going to have to write some code. i assign some roles at user creation, and others as the user supplies information, e.g. by filling out forms.

Comment: @chazsolo, I just add `{{> loginButtons}}` in menubar, all login/sign up is done automatically (both frontend and backend code)

Comment: I understand that part - my suggestion would be to read the roles documentation and write some code yourself, then edit your question with any issues you face and the related code. As it stands this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Accounts.onCreate` on server and do following:

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(joesUserId, ['manage-team','schedule-game'], 'manchester-united.com')
Roles.addUsersToRoles(joesUserId, ['player','goalie'], 'real-madrid.com')
```

Something like

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
  var role = ['admin'];
  user.roles = role
  return user;
});
```

Comment: added this code into server, but when I try to create new user, it shows `Signups forbidden`

Comment: `Accounts.config({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: false
});`